# ImportErrors cannot import app and bcrypt from flask_app and can't import db from models.py

Tags: flask, python-import

```
stucture of the app

flask_app
   __init__.py
   models.py
   routes.py
run.py
```

---

```
__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
import os
from flask_app.models import db

app = Flask(__name__)

db.init_app(app) 
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

from flask_app import routes
```

---

```
models.py

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from flask_app import app, bcrypt

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

---

```
run.py

from flask_app import app  

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  app.run(debug=True)
```

---

```
 This happens first 
 Traceback (most recent call last):


File 
   "c:\users\cristovao\documents\mqs_development\flaskexperiment\env\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\FlaskExperiment\run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_app import app  # importing from __init__.py within flask_app package
  File "C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\FlaskExperiment\flask_app\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask_app.models import db
  File "C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\FlaskExperiment\flask_app\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_app import app, bcrypt
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'flask_app' (C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\FlaskExperiment\flask_app\__init__.py)
```

---

```
 and then in models.py after this error I write from flask__app.__init__ import app bcrypt and I got another error

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cristovao\documents\mqs_development\flaskexperiment\env\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\FlaskExperiment\run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_app import app  # importing from __init__.py within flask_app package
  File "C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\FlaskExperiment\flask_app\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask_app.models import db
  File "C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\FlaskExperiment\flask_app\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_app.__init__ import app, bcrypt
  File "C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\FlaskExperiment\flask_app\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask_app.models import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'flask_app.models' (C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\FlaskExperiment\flask_app\models.py)
```

when I run my app using flask run it gives me those import errors cannot import app and bcrypt from flask_app to models.py and can't import db from models.py to __init__py. I dont understand why since run.py  is being separated from my package (flask__app).

Comment: Please post the complete error messages, incl line numbers, above in the question, and properly formatted

Comment: @J.G. I've edit my post, hope it's useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use your code, I get an error because of a circular import.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'flask_app' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/jugmac00/Tests/stackoverflow/flask_app/__init__.py)
```

I can get rid of that when I remove this line from `models.py`

```
from flask_app import app, bcrypt
```

The easiest way to get rid of circular imports is to use the app factory pattern.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/

This application factory pattern took me a while to understand, but it is really worthwile to try to understand and use it.

There is a mindblowing good video on that, from this year's Flask-Conference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNo-eOfZH5Q

If this sounds to hard, then my advice would be... just put everything in one file - that is not too bad, unless the app grows really big.